# JavaScript On Change function firing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm struggling to understand why the jQuery function "on change" will only work once for each line. The code I have works perfectly for multiple changes to each line but when I change the 'opposite value' the code fails.

I presume this is because the first selector `$( ".line" ).children()` has been set and then is not 'unset' for each. I've also looked through previous answers to similar questions without any success.

Is there a way to change this? I've tried unsetting using `.unbind()` but that just stops the code from executing after the first time.

```js
$(".line").children().on("change", function(event) {
  console.log($(this).children());
  if ($(this).children().attr("class").includes("picker")) {
    $(this).parent().find(".hex").attr("value", $(this).find(".picker").val());
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find(".picker").attr("value", $(this).find(".hex").val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col-md-12 form">
    <h3>Palette name : <span id="palette_name"></span></h3>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker3">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker4">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Update</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg pull-right cancel" href="index.html">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use `hasClass`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your problem description exactly, but [is the same error reproduced here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfb7yk66/)? Because this event listener appears to be firing exactly when I expect it to.

Comment: why not using each? $( ".form-control" ).each(function( index ) {
 
 
});

Comment: $( ".form-control" ).each(function( index ) {
 
 $(this).on("change",function(event){
  
 });
 
});

Comment: No need for `each` when setting events.   `$(".line input").on("change ...`

Comment: In your event handler, `this` will be the element that changed - so will not have any children  - you need to navigate back up to .line, ie `if ($(this).closest(".line").children()...`  also `attr` will only return a single string, so you'll need a different method for contains - as you're checking class, just ".class" - `if ($(this).closest(".line").find(".picker").length > 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change the event accessor by using

`$(".line input").on("change", func...);` instead of your code and Also the if else selectors block , it seems to work now .

kindly see below snippet

```js
$(".line input").on("change", function(event) {
  
  if ($(this).hasClass("picker")) {
  
    $(this).parents(".line").find(".hex").val( $(this).val());
    
  } else {
  
    $(this).parents(".line").find(".picker").val($(this).val());
    
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col-md-12 form">
    <h3>Palette name : <span id="palette_name"></span></h3>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker3">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <input type="color" class="form-control picker" value="#ffffff" id="picker4">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control hex" value="#ffffff" id="hex4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Update</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg pull-right cancel" href="index.html">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</form>
Javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uq80uort/

```
$( ".line" ).children().on("change",function(event){
  console.log($(this).children());
  if ($(this).children().attr("class").includes("picker")) {
    $(this).parent().find(".hex").attr("value",$(this).find(".picker").val());
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find(".picker").attr("value",$(this).find(".hex").val());
  }
});
```

Comment: You might need to clarify your definition of "worked" as the events in your fiddle do nothing

Comment: @freedomn-m here I made a video for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NifBZ3fJG-4